# ImageView, changing DemoArrayAdapter to display an image

Tags: android, listview, youtube, android-arrayadapter

Everyone. This is the code from youtube api demo. I just wanted customize the listview, instead of just display a text, I would like to add an specific image for each item in listview before the text. To clarify, where appears "Show my channel"... "My Playlist1".... it should appears an image before these texts to click on it.

I know I should modify the getview() on my DemoArrayAdapter. But how? I'm newbie. That's why I will put the code of DemoArrayAdapter.Java below

IntentDemoActivity.Java

```
package com.examples.youtubeapidemo;

import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeIntents;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.examples.youtubeapidemo.adapter.DemoArrayAdapter;
import com.examples.youtubeapidemo.adapter.DemoListViewItem;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
* A sample activity which shows how to use the {@link YouTubeIntents} static methods     to create
* Intents that navigate the user to Activities within the main YouTube application.
*/
public final class IntentsDemoActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener   {

 // This is the value of Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY for API level 11 and above.
 private static final String EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY = "android.intent.extra.LOCAL_ONLY";
 private static final String VIDEO_ID = "tKIISemrwJ8";
 private static final String PLAYLIST_ID = "PL75F25C99BA786497";
 private static final String PLAYLIST_ID2 = "PL75F25C99BA786497";
 private static final String USER_ID = "felipeneto";
 private static final int SELECT_VIDEO_REQUEST = 1000;

 private List<DemoListViewItem> intentItems;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.intents_demo);

intentItems = new ArrayList<DemoListViewItem>();
intentItems.add(new IntentItem("Show My Channel", IntentType.OPEN_USER));
intentItems.add(new IntentItem("My Playlist 1", IntentType.OPEN_PLAYLIST));
intentItems.add(new IntentItem("My Playlist 2", IntentType.OPEN_PLAYLIST2));
intentItems.add(new IntentItem("Featured", IntentType.PLAY_VIDEO));
intentItems.add(new IntentItem("Search", IntentType.OPEN_SEARCH));


ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.intent_list);
DemoArrayAdapter adapter =
    new DemoArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, intentItems);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

TextView youTubeVersionText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_version_text);
String version = YouTubeIntents.getInstalledYouTubeVersionName(this);
if (version != null) {
  String text = String.format(getString(R.string.youtube_currently_installed), version);
  youTubeVersionText.setText(text);
} else {
  youTubeVersionText.setText(getString(R.string.youtube_not_installed));
}
 }

 public boolean isIntentTypeEnabled(IntentType type) {
  switch (type) {
  case PLAY_VIDEO:
    return YouTubeIntents.canResolvePlayVideoIntent(this);
  case OPEN_PLAYLIST:
    return YouTubeIntents.canResolveOpenPlaylistIntent(this);
  case OPEN_PLAYLIST2:
      return YouTubeIntents.canResolveOpenPlaylistIntent(this);
  case PLAY_PLAYLIST:
    return YouTubeIntents.canResolvePlayPlaylistIntent(this);
  case OPEN_SEARCH:
    return YouTubeIntents.canResolveSearchIntent(this);
  case OPEN_USER:
    return YouTubeIntents.canResolveUserIntent(this);

}

return false;
 }

  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
  IntentItem clickedIntentItem = (IntentItem) intentItems.get(position);

Intent intent;
switch (clickedIntentItem.type) {
  case PLAY_VIDEO:
    intent = YouTubeIntents.createPlayVideoIntentWithOptions(this, VIDEO_ID, true, false);
    startActivity(intent);
    break;    
  case OPEN_PLAYLIST:
    intent = YouTubeIntents.createOpenPlaylistIntent(this, PLAYLIST_ID);
    startActivity(intent);
    break;
  case OPEN_PLAYLIST2:
      intent = YouTubeIntents.createOpenPlaylistIntent(this, PLAYLIST_ID2);
      startActivity(intent);
      break;
  case PLAY_PLAYLIST:
    intent = YouTubeIntents.createPlayPlaylistIntent(this, PLAYLIST_ID);
    startActivity(intent);
    break;
  case OPEN_SEARCH:
    intent = YouTubeIntents.createSearchIntent(this, USER_ID);
    startActivity(intent);
    break;
  case OPEN_USER:
    intent = YouTubeIntents.createUserIntent(this, USER_ID);
    startActivity(intent);
    break;

   }
   }

   @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent returnedIntent) {
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
  switch (requestCode) {
    case SELECT_VIDEO_REQUEST:
      Intent intent = YouTubeIntents.createUploadIntent(this, returnedIntent.getData());
      startActivity(intent);
      break;
  }
}
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, returnedIntent);
   }

  private enum IntentType {
PLAY_VIDEO,
OPEN_PLAYLIST,
OPEN_PLAYLIST2,
PLAY_PLAYLIST,
OPEN_USER,
OPEN_SEARCH,

  }

  private final class IntentItem implements DemoListViewItem {

   public final String title;
    public final IntentType type;

   public IntentItem(String title, IntentType type) {
     this.title = title;
     this.type = type;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
    return title;
    }

   public boolean isEnabled() {
     return isIntentTypeEnabled(type);
   }

    public String getDisabledText() {
     return getString(R.string.intent_disabled);
    }

    }

   }
```

DemoArrayAdapter.java. Give an example where I should modify or put to get what I want to (a different image for each item).

```
 package com.examples.youtubeapidemo.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.TextView;

import com.examples.youtubeapidemo.R;

import java.util.List;

/**
* A convenience class to make ListViews easier to use in the demo activities.
*/
public final class DemoArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DemoListViewItem> {

  private final LayoutInflater inflater;

  public DemoArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<DemoListViewItem> objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
   inflater = (LayoutInflater)    context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
   if (view == null) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

     TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_text);
     textView.setText(getItem(position).getTitle());
     TextView disabledText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_disabled_text);
    disabledText.setText(getItem(position).getDisabledText());

    if (isEnabled(position)) {
     disabledText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
     textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    } else {
     disabledText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     textView.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
    }

    return view;
    }

   @Override
   public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
    // have to return true here otherwise disabled items won't show a divider in the list.
    return true;
   }

   @Override
  public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
   return getItem(position).isEnabled();
  }

   public boolean anyDisabled() {
    for (int i = 0; i < getCount(); i++) {
     if (!isEnabled(i)) {
       return true;
      }
   }
    return false;
  }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the getView method below, the adapter references an array of images when updating the View.

mContext is initialized in the ArrayAdapter constructor

mThumbs is an array of id's referencing the images you wish to display

```
public Integer[] mThumbs{/*R.drawable.img1, R.drawable.img2,....*/};
private Context mContext;


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    if (view == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    ImageView imageView;
    if(convertView == null)// Recycled View
    {
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext); 
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
    }
    else // Re-use the view
    {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbs[position]);
    return imageView;
}
```

Hope this helps!